# Summation of terms not returning correct result

Tags: c

I have this academic project in C language. One of the exercises is calculating cos(x) without using math.h. For that, we're given a series (which I presume it's a Taylor/Maclaurin) for cos(x). For standard input, we have x angles, and k iterations.
The sum is from n=0 to k-1 of ((-1)^n*x^(2n))/(2n)!

I've tried changing in and out of cycles and fiddling with variables with no avail.

Here is the code (UPDATED):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fat(int num) {
    int fat_num=1;
    for (int cnt=1; cnt<=num; cnt++) fat_num*=cnt;
    return fat_num;
}

float expn(int x, int y) {
    int x_y=x;
    for (int cnt=1; cnt<y; cnt++) x_y*=x;
    return x_y;
}

int main() {
    const float pi = 3.1415926;
    float x; 
    scanf("%f",&x);
    int k; 
    scanf("%d", &k);
    float cosx = 0;
    int n = 0;
    x *= pi/180;
    while (n <= k-1) {
        if (n%2 == 0) 
            cosx +=    expn(x,2*n)/fat(2*n);
        else 
            cosx += -1*expn(x,2*n)/fat(2*n);
        n++;
    }
    printf("%f", cosx);
    return 0; 
}
```

***The input of 96 gives me a cossine of 0.54.***
Which is not right.

Solved: The error was in expn which had to be updated to float!

Comment: Post your `pi`.  Post input used.

Comment: @chux: const float pi = 3.1415926;

Comment: `expn(x,2*n)/fat(2*n)` do you really want to calculate expressions like that using integer math?

Comment: @Shawn Wow, didn't even notice. Changed it to float, keeps giving me a bad result. 96 degrees yields 0.54 which is way off.

Comment: @ikegami Changed code. Should compile now, and *I* did specify the input and output, even before edits.

Comment: You need to use floats internally in `fat` and `expn` to avoid overflow.

Comment: You're still not specifying (all) the inputs.

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit `int`,  the calculation of `fat(n)` will overflow if `n >= 13`.  The behaviour is therefore undefined.     That will happen for a entered value of `7` or more - and you are entering `96`.    Find a way of calculating the result without calculating `expn(x,2*n)` or `fact(2*n)` as distinct terms.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems

`expn(x,2*n)/fat(2*n)` uses integer division.

`float expn(int x, int y)` uses an `int x`.  Need floating point `x`.

```
// int expn(int x, int y) {
float expn(float x, int y) {
  float x_y = 1;
  for (int cnt = 0; cnt < y; cnt++)
    x_y *= x;
  return x_y;
}
```

---

Code has various efficiencies.

An alternative that does not need `k` - some food for thought.

```
static double my_cos_helper(double xx, double term, unsigned n) {
  if (term + 1.0 == 1.0) {
    return term;
  }
  return term - xx * my_cos_helper(xx, term / ((n + 1) * (n + 2)), n + 2);
}

double my_cos(double x) {
  return my_cos_helper(x * x, 1.0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Tried the changes, still getting an incorrect result.